# Instance variable in ruby acting like class variable

Tags: ruby, variables, instance-variables, class-variables

@ - instance variable
@@ - class variable.

So instance variable value shouldn't be shared if no instance is created. But:

```
class Add

  def self.add(what)
    if not defined? @a
      @a = 0
    end
    @a += what
    puts @a.to_s
  end
end

Add.add(4)
Add.add(4)
```

Results in:

```
$ruby main.rb

4
8
```

Why?

Comment: Aside: `@a ||= 0` is a commonly-used replacement for `if not defined? @a...`.  The former is shorthand for `@a = @a || 0`, just as `x += 1` is for `x = x + 1`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Every class in Ruby is also an object, instance of `Class` class. So, your `@a` is simply instance variable of `Add` class.

Comment: Ok then why Add.add(4) run for the second time results in 8. @a is not global

Comment: @user665967 it's because `@a` is instance variable of `Add` class. When you modify instance variable value of some object, and that object persist, its instance variable persists as well.

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong, so basically @variables in Class methods are instance variables but automatically become Class variables on the Object level

Comment: @user665967 no. The point is that in Ruby every class is also an object with all consequences. One of these consequences is the fact that it has its own instance variables. So if you define "class method" and you use instance variable inside of it, this instance variable belongs to this class instance. And, what's important, it's NOT a class variable, which is a bit different concept.

Comment: Marek, how can I contact you? :)

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/41552/discussion-between-marek-lipka-and-user665967)

Answer (score 2):

The `@a` you are referring to in the [singleton method](http://rubymonk.com/learning/books/4-ruby-primer-ascent/chapters/39-ruby-s-object-model/lessons/131-singleton-methods-and-metaclasses) is an instance variable of Add's class.

You have effectively changed the scope of the method declaration to the eigenclass when you have defined the method as `def self.add` instead of `def add`.

Comment: Why 'eigenclass'? It's an instance variable of object itself (which is `Add` class), not its eigenclass:
`(class << Add; self end).instance_variable_get(:@a) # => nil`

Comment: @MarekLipka please, read up the section about class methods in the second link and you might reconsider the downvote. tl;dr: all class methods are housed in the eigenclass of the particular Class instance.

Comment: it's not about "class method" (which is, of course, right that they are housed in eigenclassess of the particular `Class` instance). It's about instance variables. Please take my example into consideration.

Comment: @MarekLipka - I see, you're right. Leave the downvote, it is deserved. Thank you for this small instant of enlightenment :) I will remove the eigenclass.